# run grep and wc -l in multiple files in recursive manner

Tags: grep, find, wc

I have multiple fasta files I want to count the lines starting with ">" (no quotes).

What I usually do is

```
grep ">" file.fasta | wc -l
```

This works for one file at the time. I'm trying different alternatives using *find* command but nothing seems to do the trick. What I want at the end is a line by line, file name and count the lines starting with >. Ideally it has to be a one-liner

Comment: Just use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`grep` can do the counting for you with its `-c` flag, so `wc -l` is not needed.  Also, `grep` takes multiple files as input, if you provide them.

For example,

```
grep -c '^>' some/dir/*.fa
```

To do it recursively, use `grep -Rc '^>' dirname` if you have a `grep` that knows the `-R` option (this would run over *all* files), otherwise use `find`:

```
find dirname -type f \( -name '*.fa' -o -name '*.fasta' \) -exec grep -c '^>' /dev/null {} +
```

The extra `/dev/null` in the command above ensures that `grep` gets at least two input files, which in turn ensures that it will always display the name of the file that it processes (it does not do that with a single input file).  One could also use `-H` with `grep`, although this is a non-standard option.

Or, with your original command plugged into a loop that is fed with pathnames from `find`:

```
find dirname -type f \( -name '*.fa' -o -name '*.fasta' \) -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        printf "Counting in %s...\n" "$pathname"
        grep "^>" "$pathname" | wc -l
    done' sh {} +
```

Since your command does not report the filename by itself, I added a `printf` statement that mentions it.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: On the small change that grep ends up with a set of only 1 file, you might want to add `-H`

Comment: @glennjackman Added something about that. Thanks